# Using sessions to display the profile of a logged in user from a database with PHP

Tags: php, session

I have been having an issue selecting data from my database based on the user id column. I know that I have to make use of PHP sessions to enable each user see their profile when they login, but I haven't been able to work out the code for this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php session_start(); include 'dpconfig.php'; $id = $_SESSION['uid'] ?>

<?php

    $run = mysqli_query($conn,"Select * from user Where first = '$id'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run, MYSQLI_BOTH); {}

    $showid = $row[0];

    $showfirst = $row[1]; 

    $showlast = $row[2];

    echo  $showid;

    echo      $showfirst;

    echo       $showlast;

?>
```

If I run the above code I get nothing echoed out, but if I remove the `WHERE` clause from my `SELECT` statement, all logged in users see the first column of my database.

I want each user to see their own profile, I learnt that I need to authenticate session, and I am confused. Please help.

Comment: What is `first`? Is this the user's first name? Because that shouldn't be equal to the UID. Maybe you have an ID column that you should be checking in your WHERE clause instead?

Comment: first is the user's first name and to me the code meant 'select data from table where firstname and username are equal or like have the same id..maybe am wrong, pls correct me.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assumptions

- I'm assuming your database has three columns, `uid` (the id of a user, int, primary key, auto_increment), `first` (the user's first name, varchar) and `last` (the user's last name, varchar).
- I'm also assuming that when the user logs in, `$_SESSION["UID"]` is set to the value of the `id` column in their row.

### Solution

As far as I can see, your `WHERE` clause is wrong. You wrote

> Select * from user Where first = '$id'

which essentially means "Select everything from the `user` table where the first name is equal to the currently logged in user's id". I think you meant something more like

```
SELECT first, last FROM user WHERE uid='$id'
```

which means "Select the first and last names from the `user` table where the id is equal to the currently logged in user's id".

### Code

I have re-written your PHP file, to make it a bit more readable and clear. You'll need to change the MySQL connection to whatever you were originally using, but apart from that, everything should work fine.

```
<?php
session_start();
require("dpconfig.php");
$q = "SELECT first, last FROM user WHERE uid='".$_SESSION["UID"]."'";
$r = mysqli_query($conn,$q);
$a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
echo "First Name: ".$a["first"]."<br>";
echo "Last Name:".$a["last"];
?>
```

### Second Question

For your form:

```
<form method="post" action="update.php">
    <input type="text" name="status"><br>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

For `update.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require("dpconfig.php");
    if (isset($_POST["status"])) {
        $q = "UPDATE user SET status='".addslashes($_POST["status"])."' WHERE uid='".$_SESSION["uid"]."'";
        mysqli_query($conn,$q);
    }
    header("Location:./");
?>
```

Comment: just tried out the code you sent me, it gives me undefined index:uid, undefined variable c and : mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, I believe we are close, Thanks for assisting

Comment: am not sure if , $_SESSION["UID"] is set to the value of the id column in their row when users log in..how do i know pls..

Comment: I've changed the connection statement to what you originally had, this should now connect to the database correctly. When you log a user in, what do you set `$_SESSION["UID"]` to? There'll be a line in the code that logs the user in that says something like `$_SESSION["UID"] = something` - copy and paste that in as a comment, and I'll see if I can help :)

Comment: <?php
   if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['uid']; }
   else {
       echo "You are not Logged In!";  header("Location: header.php"); }
?   Thats what i have and Thanks so far

Comment: Hmm, is there a login form on `header.php`? Where does the `action` attribute on that form lead to? Open up the file referenced in there, and then do a FIND in your text editor for `$_SESSION["uid"] =`. Copy and paste that line in here.

Comment: Yh, i have a login form on header.php and the form action leads to signin.php and what i have their is 
if (!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "Your Username or Password Is Incorrect!";
} else {
 $_SESSION['uid']= $row['uid'];
 
}..   Thanks for your time

Comment: Awesome! So `$_SESSION["uid"]` is set to the value of the `uid` column for  logged in user in your database. I have updated by answer to reflect this - try it now.

Comment: You have a long name, i wish i could pronounce it, you made my day..Am so grateful..It worked atlast..

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing please

Comment: Yeah, sure, you can ask me one more thing :D Also, if this helped you, could you click the green check next to my answer? Thanks :)

Comment: i would gladly do that,  Thanks, i want users to be able to update their database, i have a column in my database known as status and i want user to be able to update that column if they want to just  by writing in a text box and clicking a submit button, the action for the button is update.php still with the same database table as the previous question , so how do i go about it pls

Comment: You are a darling, Thank you so much, i will try out the code soon and comment the output..Thanks for everything ..

Comment: Am so confused, am not getting any error and changes are not reflecting in the user database..What do you think is wrong

Comment: Remove the `header` line at the bottom of the code and tell me what it says when you run the code again.

Comment: I removed the header code and now it says undefined index : status in update.php file..

Comment: Ha! I made a **very** small typo and had put a space in-front of the bit where I had typed status - i.e. I'd typed `$_POST["status"]` as `$_POST[" status"]` - hence it wasn't working. Copy and paste my code into `update.php` now and it should work :D

Comment: Wow..you are so gud at this, Toastrackenigma, i am happy  i could have someone as patient as you assist me , A  VERY Big Thank you to you..

Comment: Hello, i need your help pls

Comment: @Caroline What do you need help with?

Comment: K, Thanks for answering me, am creating a php site and have wriiten all my codes with sublime text , and now am using wordpress and i want to make php pages like example.com/login.php in wordpress, i read that you can use theme editor, m still confused though, i dont know what to do. Thanks again ..

Comment: i used a plugin called insert php to create my registration form and i edited a template file to signup.php, i set my registration form action to signup.php..but it says page cannot be found, how can i link the file i edited in my template file to be my form action..Thanks for your help so far..